# maxScrollV doesn't take into account html image size <img> for scrolling textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using Flash Pro CS6. I have built a scrolling textfield which is injected with htmltext through XML.

The problem I am having is the maxScrollV doesn't seem to take into account my images . I have tried to set the dimensions in the html `<img src='assets/images/test.png' height='330' width='330' />` but this seems to throw out the wordwrap.

```
public class ScrollingTextField extends Sprite
{
    private var myText:TextField;
    private var myFormat:TextFormat;
    private var bounds:Rectangle;
    private var boundHeight:Number;
    private var slider:SliderImage;

    public function ScrollingTextField()
    {
        trace("ScrollingTextField added");
        myText = new TextField();
        myFormat = new TextFormat();
        slider = new SliderImage();

        myFormat.font = "Arial";
        myFormat.color = 0x333333;
        myFormat.size = 14;
        addChild(myText);

        myText.htmlText = "init";
        myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
        myText.wordWrap = true;
        myText.multiline = true;
        myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
        myText.selectable = false;

        this.addChild(slider);

        slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSlider);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkSlider);
    }

    private function dragSlider(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        slider.startDrag();
        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSlider);
        slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropSlider);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,moveSlider);
    }

    private function dropSlider(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        slider.stopDrag();
        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropSlider);
        slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSlider);
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,moveSlider);
    }

    private function moveSlider(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        evt.updateAfterEvent();
        if (evt.buttonDown)
        {
            slider.startDrag(false,bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            slider.stopDrag();
        }
    }

    private function checkSlider(evt:Event):void
    {
        myText.scrollV = ((slider.y - bounds.y)* (myText.maxScrollV)/boundHeight);
    }

    public function textToDisplay(txt:String):void
    {
        myText.htmlText = txt;
        myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
    }

    public function setDimensions(w:Number, h:Number):void
    {
        boundHeight = h - slider.height;
        bounds = new Rectangle(w + 20,10,0,h - slider.height);
        slider.x = w + 20;
        slider.y = 10;
        myText.width = w;
        myText.height = h;
    }

    public function checkTextFieldSize():void
    {
        trace("numLines = " + myText.numLines);
        trace("text height = " + myText.textHeight);
        trace("height = " + myText.height);
        if (myText.textHeight < myText.height)
        {
            slider.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            slider.visible = true;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Just to add. I have moved the <img> element up to the top of the page, and it adds in the scroll button, but cuts off the first line of text and the last portion also. The maxScrollV value changed from 1 to 16. There is no change when the <img> element is at the bottom of the page. Bizarre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing a cheap workaround. From scouring the net, it seems that .maxScrollV just doesn't like .htmltext. I'll take it to Adobe... in the meantime adding in `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to the html a load of times to act as the image space, seems to do the trick.